# Why does simulator SDK provide more APIs than iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I saw many frameworks available on the simulator but not on iOS, e.g.

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework

doesn't have counterpart under

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

What are they for? I suppose we shouldn't call any APIs from such frameworks.